# Websocket connection fails for safe app after wagmi and walletconnect upgrade

Tags: gnosis-safe, walletconnect, wagmi

We have upgraded our application to wagmi 0.12.0 and walletconnect 2.7.8 with it.
Now the websocket connections are failing when using it as a safe app:

[image]

"Uncaught (in promise) Error: closeTransport called before connection was established...
ws.ts:133 WebSocket connection to 'wss://relay.walletconnect.com/?auth=...' failed...
index.js:82 WebSocket connection to 'wss://safe-walletconnect.safe.global/?env=browser&host=app.safe.global&protocol=wc&version=1' failed...
vendor-modern.a1c39d6c.js:2 WebSocket connection to 'wss://nexus-websocket-a.intercom.io/...' failed..."

We are creating the wagmi client with the SafeConnector:

```
export const supportedChains = [goerli]

const { chains, provider } = configureChains(
  [goerli],
  [
    jsonRpcProvider({
      rpc: (chain) => {
        return { http: rpcUrls[goerli.id] }
      }
    })
  ]
)
const client = createClient({
  autoConnect: false,
  connectors: [
    new InjectedConnector({ chains }),
    new WalletConnectConnector({
      chains,
      options: {
        showQrModal: true,
        projectId: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WALLET_CONNECT_PROJECT_ID}`
      }
    }),
    new SafeConnector({
      chains: supportedChains,
      options: {
        debug: true
      }
    })
  ],
  provider
})
```

Metamask and walletconnect works if we are not using the app from safe wallet.
Any suggestion why this is happening?